# GraphQL error: Default value for $completedAt doesn't match type DateTime in React Apollo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have a mutation like this -

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";

const completedAt = new Date().toISOString();

export const CREATE_TODO = gql`
  mutation($body: String!, $completedAt: DateTime = completedAt) {
    createTodo(input: { body: $body, completed_at: $completedAt }) {
      id
      body
    }
  }
`;
```

When I call this mutation I get the error

> GraphQL error: Default value for $completedAt doesn't match type
>   DateTime in React Apollo

How do I solve this? I have tried `JSON.stringify(new Date().toISOString())` too but no luck :(

Also, note that this works -

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";

const completedAt = JSON.stringify(new Date().toISOString());

export const CREATE_TODO = gql`
  mutation($body: String!) {
    createTodo(input: { body: $body, completed_at: ${completedAt} }) {
      id
      body
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my solution. Right now, what I do is I don't use **completedAt** like that. I take it as an input to GraphQL variable like:

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";

export const CREATE_TODO = gql`
  mutation createTodo($body: String!, $completedAt: DateTime) {
    createTodo(input: { body: $body, completed_at: $completedAt }) {
      id
      body
      completed_at
    }
  }
`;
```

And then, as **$completedAt** is not a **required** field, I send **null** if I don't want any value or I send **new Date().toISOString()** if I want it to have the current time.

For example:

#### Incomplete Todo, i.e, Null value for DateTime

```
mutate({
    query: CREATE_TODO,
    variables: { body: "Incomplete todo", completedAt: null }
});
```

#### Complete Todo, i.e, Current time for DateTime

```
mutate({
    query: CREATE_TODO,
    variables: { body: "Complete todo", completedAt: new Date().toISOString() }
});
```